# Onclick Change Div Title

Tags: javascript, html

I like to change Title of a div using onclick function. I a new to .js

```
function changeTitle() {
    document.getElementById("amul").attr('title', 'Item Added');

}
```

This is the input button where i have inserted my onclick function

```
<input type="button" class="button2" id="item1" value="Add to Cart" title="Add to Cart" onClick="addItem_check('item_listing_100','ItemTable','100','Amul Butter','500','g','150.00','1','kg','200.00','2','kg','250.00'); amul.style.backgroundColor='#c2ed5c'; if(this.value=='Add to Cart') {this.value = 'Remove from Cart'}; item1();  "/>
```

This is the div which i like to change the title

```
<div class="center_prod_box" id="amul">. . . </div>
```

Comment: `title` is not really a standard attribute of `div` elements although many browsers will interpret it anyway (and often display the title when the element is hovered, like an `a` title). in html5 this doesn't matter as you can set whatever attributes you damn well please, but i wonder if maybe you are looking to edit the content of the `div` in question rather than its attributes?

Answer (score 7):

You're mixing plain JavaScript (`getElementById`) with jQuery (`attr`), the two methods are incompatible. Try one of these:

```
// Plain JS (recommended)
document.getElementById("amul").title = "Item Added";

// Plain JS, may not work in <= IE7
document.getElementById("amul").setAttribute("title", "Item Added")

// jQuery (recommended)
$('#amul').attr('title', 'Item Added');

// You can also get the native JS object from a jQuery object
$('#amul')[0].title = "Item Added";
$('#amul')[0].setAttribute("title", "Item Added")
```

Answer (score 4):

You may utilize the [`title`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) property:

```
document.getElementById("amul").title = "Item Added";
```

Or, use the [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) method:

```
document.getElementById("amul").setAttribute("title", "Item Added");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
document.getElementById("amul").setAttribute("title", "Item Added");
```